# font size issue in flutter by using `Text.rich()` or `RichText`

Tags: android, flutter, dart, styles

I used `Text.rich()` or `RichText` with font size 25. but the size of `RichText` is looking greater than the `Text.rich()` please tell me why the size is different, I specified `font Size 25` for both widgets.

**This code showing small font size:**

```dart
runApp(MaterialApp(
    theme: ThemeData(fontFamily: "nunito"),
    home: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("PUROGRAMMER")),
      body: Center(child: Container(
        child: Text.rich(
         TextSpan(
           style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.grey),
           children: [
                  TextSpan(text: "Click"),
                  TextSpan(text: " + ", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                  TextSpan(text: "to add")
           ]
         )
         )),)
    ),
  ));
```

**And this is showing large font size:**

```dart
runApp(MaterialApp(
    theme: ThemeData(fontFamily: "nunito"),
    home: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("PUROGRAMMER")),
      body: Center(child: Container(
        child: TRichText(
         text: TextSpan(
           style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.grey),
           children: [
                  TextSpan(text: "Click"),
                  TextSpan(text: " + ", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                  TextSpan(text: "to add")
           ]
         )
         )),)
    ),
  ));
```

Comment: add your code snippet

Comment: Please add your Code Snippet, this will help us answer your question

Comment: I have added Code Snippet, please check now

Answer (score 7):

In the Text widget's constructor, the `textScaleFactor` parameter is not initialized. In the build method, if `textScaleFactor` is not initialized, then `MediaQuery.textScaleFactorOf(context)` is used.

In the `RichText` widget's constructor, the parameter `textScaleFactor = 1.0`, in the `createRenderObject/updateRenderObject` methods, it is used directly, without a fallback to `MediaQuery.textScaleFactorOf(context)`.

Bottom line, you can solve this problem like this:

1. Use

`final tsf = MediaQuery.of(context).textScaleFactor`

to

`RichText(textScaleFactor: tsf)`.

2. Use `Text.rich()`

---

Update: `textScaleFactor` is marked as deprecated with this comment:

> Use textScaler instead. Use of textScaleFactor was deprecated in preparation for the upcoming nonlinear text scaling support. This feature was deprecated after v3.12.0-2.0.pre.

In addition, there are now optimized `MediaQuery.of` calls for each tracked field. So now you can do this:

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final textScaler = MediaQuery.textScalerOf(context);
  return RichText(text: ..., textScaler: textScaler);
}
```

Comment: Newer vesion would be `textScaler: MediaQuery.of(context).textScaler,`. Great answer, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

In `RichText` if you don’t explicitly define all attributes of text style, it will copy the style regarding the position of text, for instance in a `Column` in a `Scaffold` with white background define a `Text.Rich` and `RichText`, you’ll see that `RichText` is painted in white; or if you declare a style only for the `text` attribute the `children` `TextSpan`s will copy that as well.
So the difference you see is most probably because of their `fontWeight`, define a same for both and see if they look identical.

*Update after the code snippet is provided:*

This is what I get running your two containers in a column:

[image]

but if you remove the `color: Colors.grey` for both widgets this is what I get (`TextRich` becomes white):

[image]

but if you put them in an `appbar` like this:

```
AppBar(
    
    title: Column(
      children: [
        Container(
          child:
              Text.rich(TextSpan(style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20), children: [
            TextSpan(text: "Click"),
            TextSpan(
                text: " + ",
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.red, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
            TextSpan(text: "to add")
          ])),
        ),
        Container(
          child: RichText(
              text: TextSpan(style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20), children: [
            TextSpan(text: "Click"),
            TextSpan(
                text: " + ",
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.red, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
            TextSpan(text: "to add")
          ])),
        )
      ],
    ),
  ),
```

this is what you get:
[image]

as you can see they both turn white since it's the default text color of the appbar, but they have different `fontWeight` and thats because `RichText` copies the default `fontWeight` of appbar style, but if you declare `fontWeight` in the child `textstyle` like this:

```
AppBar(
    title: Column(
      children: [
        Container(
          child: Text.rich(TextSpan(
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              children: [
                TextSpan(text: "Click"),
                TextSpan(
                    text: " + ",
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.red, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                TextSpan(text: "to add")
              ])),
        ),
        Container(
          child: RichText(
              text: TextSpan(
                  style:
                      TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  children: [
                TextSpan(text: "Click"),
                TextSpan(
                    text: " + ",
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.red, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                TextSpan(text: "to add")
              ])),
        )
      ],
    ),
  ),
```

this is what you get:

[image]

Comment: After your answer, I gave the `fontWeight` but it still not working but I have added a code snippet in my question. Please check it and tell me the solution.

Comment: @PuroGrammer check the edit.

Answer (score 0):

I also get this issue with RichText widget in my app i have set the font family in my ThemeData but RichText is not picking that font so i externally give the font family to RichText

```
TextStyle(
    fontFamily: "Serif",
    fontSize: 30,
    color: Colors.black,
    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
  )
```

In RichText your style should contain your font family

Or else You can use **Text.Rich** it is working as expected.